# Extra values being inserted into d3 chart ordinal domain

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I'm trying to create a basic d3 pie chart with a legend.  I'm following the examples in two different tutorials and somehow code from one example isn't playing well with the other.  What I'm trying to do is set an ordinal scale's domain so I can use that to create a legend.

On the following line, I set the domain.  If I step through the code, I can see that immediately after I get ["HEURISTIC", "ADWARE", "COMPANY_BLACK_LIST", "PUP", "SUSPECTED_MALWARE", "KNOWN_MALWARE"].  This is exactly what I want.

```
color.domain(labels)
```

However, if I keep stepping through, once I reach the following line, the domain changes to ["HEURISTIC", "ADWARE", "COMPANY_BLACK_LIST", "PUP", "SUSPECTED_MALWARE", "KNOWN_MALWARE", **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5**]

```
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
    .attr("d", arc);
```

**QUESTION: What is causing those six extra items to be inserted into the domain?**

Code (http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/2urZY/5/):

```
var w = 150,
    h = 100,
    r = 50,
    color = d3.scale.category20c(),
    dataset = [{"name":"HEURISTIC","value":65},{"name":"ADWARE","value":75},{"name":"COMPANY_BLACK_LIST","value":9},{"name":"PUP","value":34},{"name":"SUSPECTED_MALWARE","value":14},{"name":"KNOWN_MALWARE","value":156}],
    labels = _.pluck(dataset, "name");

color.domain(labels);

var chart = d3.select("#pie_chart")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .data([dataset])
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + w + " " + h)
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet");

var vis = chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w - r) + "," + r + ")");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "slice");

arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
    .attr("d", arc);

var legend = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "pie-legend")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 7 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 5)
    .attr("height",5)
    .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Here is what the chart looks like so far:

[image: pie chart with extra legend values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your ordinal scale domain with strings, but then calling it with index numbers.  If you ask an ordinal scale for a value that isn't currently in its domain, it will add it to the domain and assign it the next value in the range (or recycle the range values if it runs out).

Original code:

```
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
    .attr("d", arc);
```

Should be

```
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return color( d.data.name); } )
    .attr("d", arc);
```

The `d` value is the object created by the pie chart function; it stores the original data object as `d.data`.  The name from that data is one of the values used in the color scale domain.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2urZY/6/

Comment: P.S.  If you don't like the irregular colour pattern, either set the colour scale domain after sorting the data by value, or tell the pie chart function not to sort the data by using [`.sort(null)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pie-Layout#wiki-sort): http://jsfiddle.net/2urZY/7/

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks, not only did you solve my problem but I learned a great lesson about how d3 works!